# Do Loop and If Statement in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

In the WorkSheet, I'm trying to create the following logic in Excel Macro.

Logic:

```
Dub Test()

Dim rws as integer
Dim counter as integer

rws = 6   
counter = 2

Do while rws <> 0
    IF 'Data Sheet with Space'!J`counter` = "Sample Data Row 1 Col 10" Then
        WorkSheet!A`counter` = 'Data Sheet with Space'!A`counter`
    end IF

    counter = counter + 1
    rws = rws - 1
```

The Excel sheets are:

`Data Sheet with Space`

```
---------------------------------------------
Header 1                 Header 2                 Header 3                 Header 4                 Header 5                 Header 6                 Header 7                 Header 8                 Header 9                 Header 10                
Sample Data Row 1 Col 1  Sample Data Row 1 Col 2  Sample Data Row 1 Col 3  Sample Data Row 1 Col 4  Sample Data Row 1 Col 5  Sample Data Row 1 Col 6  Sample Data Row 1 Col 7  Sample Data Row 1 Col 8  Sample Data Row 1 Col 9  Sample Data Row 1 Col 10 
Sample Data Row 2 Col 1  Sample Data Row 2 Col 2  Sample Data Row 2 Col 3  Sample Data Row 2 Col 4  Sample Data Row 2 Col 5  Sample Data Row 2 Col 6  Sample Data Row 2 Col 7  Sample Data Row 2 Col 8  Sample Data Row 2 Col 9  Sample Data Row 2 Col 10 
Sample Data Row 3 Col 1  Sample Data Row 3 Col 2  Sample Data Row 3 Col 3  Sample Data Row 3 Col 4  Sample Data Row 3 Col 5  Sample Data Row 3 Col 6  Sample Data Row 3 Col 7  Sample Data Row 3 Col 8  Sample Data Row 3 Col 9  Sample Data Row 3 Col 10 
Sample Data Row 4 Col 1  Sample Data Row 4 Col 2  Sample Data Row 4 Col 3  Sample Data Row 4 Col 4  Sample Data Row 4 Col 5  Sample Data Row 4 Col 6  Sample Data Row 4 Col 7  Sample Data Row 4 Col 8  Sample Data Row 4 Col 9  Sample Data Row 4 Col 10 
Sample Data Row 5 Col 1  Sample Data Row 5 Col 2  Sample Data Row 5 Col 3  Sample Data Row 5 Col 4  Sample Data Row 5 Col 5  Sample Data Row 5 Col 6  Sample Data Row 5 Col 7  Sample Data Row 5 Col 8  Sample Data Row 5 Col 9  Sample Data Row 5 Col 10 
---------------------------------------------
```

and the other Excel sheet called `WorkSheet`

When trying to run the macro I get an error the `'` in the `Data Sheet with Space` name causes an error.

Secondly, I an having an error when trying to change the input and output cell number dynamically using the `counter` variable.

Any help is appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the way in which you address the cells.

If you want to refer to cell "B6" on the first sheet, there are basically 3 ways to refer to the sheet:

1. By CodeName (If you happen to know the codename of the sheet)

   ```
   Sheet1.[B6]
   ```
2. By Name (That is the name you see on the tab of the sheet)

   ```
   Sheets("Data Sheet with Space").[B6]
   ```
3. By Number (If you happen to know the order of the sheets)

   ```
   Sheets(1).[B6]
   ```

It is your code, you are going to maintain it, so use whichever looks best to you.
You might prefer to use a variable: `wsData = Sheets("Data Sheet with Space")`, so you could simply write `wsOther.[A1]=wsData.[B6]`.

---

There are also several ways to refer to the cells on the sheet. Some usefull ones:

1. Directly using the Address:

   ```
   Sheets("Data Sheet with Space").[B6]
   ```
2. By using `.Range` (using the Address)

   ```
   Sheets("Data Sheet with Space").Range("B6")
   ```
3. By using `.Cell` (using the Coordinates)

   ```
   Sheets("Data Sheet with Space").Cells(6, 2)
   ```
4. A more reeadable way of using `.Cell` (as sugessted by YowE3K)

   ```
   Sheets("Data Sheet with Space").Cells(6, "B")
   ```

In your code, you are already using coordinates. So you might prefer to use `.Cells(rws, counter)`. But it's up to you.

Comment: @jsheeran: In this cae, that would be: ['Data Sheet with Space'!B6]. But I agree, that is probably the most readable way.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from your ' in the code. (Easily visible already here in grey). If I understood your code correctly then you should correct it by entering real sheets and range as below (not tested):

```
Sub Test2()

Dim rws As Integer
Dim counter As Integer

rws = 6
counter = 2

Do While rws <> 0

If Sheets("Data Sheet with Space").Range("J" & counter).Value = Cells(1, 10).Value Then


Sheets("WorkSheet").Range("A" & counter).Value = Sheets("Data Sheet with Space").Range("A" & counter).Value

End If

counter = counter + 1
rws = rws - 1
Loop 

End Sub
```

Comment: your code won't complie, since you are not closing your `Do While rws <> 0`

Comment: Oops missed that